# production.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: The separation symbol could not be found

Tags: laravel

I have this in my code in my Laravel-5.8 model:

HrEmployee

```
public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
}

public function getDateOfBirthAttribute($input)
{
       return $input ? Carbon::parse($input)->format(config('app.date_format')) : 'Unknown';
}
```

When I wanted to execute this:

```
        $payloads = [
            'first_name'                            => $clientdata['first_name'],
            'last_name'                             => $clientdata['last_name'],
            'other_name'                            => $clientdata['middle_name'],
            'date_of_birth'                         => Carbon::parse($clientdata['date_of_birth'])->toDateString(),
            'hr_status'                             => $clientdata['hr_status'],
            'address'                               => $clientdata['residential_address_1'],
            'hire_date'                             => Carbon::parse($clientdata['hire_date'])->toDateString(),
            'exit_interview_date'                   => Carbon::parse($clientdata['exit_interview_date'])->toDateString(),
        ]; 

        $employee = HrEmployee::updateOrCreate([
                    'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],
                ], $payloads);
```

I got this error:

```
[2020-09-04 10:16:19] production.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: The separation symbol could not be found
    Trailing data in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:623
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php(645): Carbon\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('d-m-Y', '1964-12-12', NULL)
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Models\Hr\HrEmployee.php(155): Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '1964-12-12')
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(615): App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee->setDateOfBirthAttribute('1964-12-12')
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(569): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->setMutatedAttributeValue('date_of_birth', '1964-12-12')
    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(329): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->setAttribute('date_of_birth', '1964-12-12')
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(436): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fill(Array)
    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(1124): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}(Object(App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee))
    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(437): tap(Object(App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee), Object(Closure))
    #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->updateOrCreate(Array, Array)
    #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1618): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'updateOrCreate', Array)
```

The error has to do with the date_of_birth.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) `toDateString` returns something like `1975-12-25` so `Y-m-d`, so you are using the wrong format on the model mutator (since you are using `d-m-Y`)

Comment: How do I format the date_of_birth in carbon to d-m-Y

Comment: @mikefolu change the code on the controller to `->format("d-m-Y")`